# How to add extensions in a list?

Tags: python, list

For example:

I have a list and need to add ".jpg" to all elements in a list in python.

Input:

```
a = [[0, 1, 5], [3, 4, 6, 7], [2]]
```

output:

```
[[0.jpg, 1.jpg, 5.jpg], [3.jpg, 4.jpg, 6.jpg, 7.jpg], [2.jpg]]
```

hope someone here could help. I'm open to any ideas, recommendation and suggestion, thank you.

Comment: Your output isn't valid syntactically. Assuming you mean e.g. `"0.jpg"`, what have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
>>> [[str(element) + '.jpg' for element in sublist] for sublist in a]
[['0.jpg', '1.jpg', '5.jpg'], ['3.jpg', '4.jpg', '6.jpg', '7.jpg'], ['2.jpg']]
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael H. solved my problem!